# ESD Protection for LED

Tags: led, switching, esd

I have a main board with microcontroller and two long distance panel boards with standard 5mm red LEDs with 3.3k resistors. I supply panel boards with 24V over 20m cable. Whole system power is supplied with [Meanwell SMPS](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/LRS-100/LRS-100-SPEC.PDF). I use [ULN2003](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2001.pdf) open collector transistor array for switching LEDs with my microcontroller. So, I draw ULN2003 like switch in schematic. Panel boards is in a plastic box.

My original schematic:

[image]

The problem: My LEDs in panel boards, fail after a few months. Mostly, not in same time for two panels. I think some ESD occurs and breaks my LEDs. I searched and find this kind of protections.

First one, TVS:

[image: What I found]

And diode solutions:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9DyKK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Red rectange is my main board. I show my power supply and reverse voltage protection. Switches are ULN2003 outputs.

Finally, which is the best choice for protecting LEDs from ESD events?

Edit: [LED Datasheet](https://docdro.id/Km9xI7p)

Comment: LED data sheet required. How many LEDs in series in one string? One or many? More likely it's indirect lightning protection that you need rather than ESD protection. Why do you have 30 volts on one diagram and 24 volts on the others? Inconsistencies are not helpful. It could also be reverse breakdown too. LEDs are generally not that good on reverse breakdown voltage i.e. 10 volts can kill them.

Comment: **Don't** use solution 1 as a reverse voltage will divide across LED and 1N4007. It will work but solution 2 is better as the LED cannot get a reverse voltage of more than 1 V. Also consider a 10 uF capacitor in parallel with the LED to absorb voltage spikes. Is some person / object able to touch the wires to the LEDs? If **no** then it cannot be an ESD event. I think induced voltages due to lightning or other equipment is more likely.

Comment: @Andyaka Hi Andy. I added dataheet. 24V power supplies can vary mostly 20-30V. Actually I use it with 24V. Also, (30V-2.1V)/3.3k =  0.008 A. It is much lower than maximum forward current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie 10uF electrolytic capacitor or non-polarized capacitor differs? Lightning is another possibility but It's impossible to find out which is my real problem.

Comment: That's one dodgy looking data sheet. It's flashing up telling me I'm a lucky winner and I wouldn't use that LED on that basis alone.